# Expose a HTTP-SOAP service using Apache Camel (with DSL)

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, apache-camel, cxf

I am trying to expose a HTTP-SOAP web service using apache camel (I'm not using spring, I'm using DSL) with the below WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://javainuse.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    targetNamespace="http://javainuse.com">

    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://javainuse.com">
            <xs:element name="inputSOATest">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="test" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="outputSOATest">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="result" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>


<!--Define input and output parameters -->
    <wsdl:message name="inputSOATest">
        <wsdl:part name="in" element="tns:inputSOATest" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="outputSOATest">
        <wsdl:part name="out" element="tns:outputSOATest" />
    </wsdl:message>

<!--Define port definition -->
    <wsdl:portType name="SOATestEndpoint">
        <wsdl:operation name="SOATest">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:inputSOATest" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:outputSOATest" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

<!--Bind Soap operation and service -->
    <wsdl:binding name="SOATestBinding" type="tns:SOATestEndpoint">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="SOATest">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://javainuse.com"
                style="document" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body parts="in" use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body parts="out" use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>

<!--Define service -->
    <wsdl:service name="SOATestEndpointService">
        <wsdl:port name="SOATestEndpoint" binding="tns:SOATestBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8181/cxf/javainuse/learn" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Could you please guide me how I can expose the service which will accept an soap xml and send back a soap response to the client.

Please help me with some sample code.

Comment: Can someone help me here please!